# Department not null filter for IGraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest (GraphServiceClient)

Tags: c#, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How to create not null filter for department property to get users by GraphServiceClient?

```
department ne null
```

and

```
NOT(department eq null)
```

don't work

My current code:

```
var request = _graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Filter($"department ne null");
        
var usersPage = await request.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering by `department` requires adding header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` and `$count` parameter must be set to `true`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) `department` is returned only on `$select`. It means that if you need to know the value of `department` you have to add `Select` method and specify all properties to be returned including `department`.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};

var request = await _graphClient.Users
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .Select("id,displayName,department") // and other properties
    .Filter("department ne null"); // .Filter("NOT(department eq null)") should also work

var usersPage = await request.GetAsync();
```

Resources:

[Advanced queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#user-properties)

[User properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)